# "Went right past" in Spanish

Tags: traducción

> He went past the red light

I know the above sentence can be translated into Spanish as:

> Pasó la luz roja.

Is there a better translation to this, one that the locals use?

Also, how would one translate this:

> He went "right" past the red light and met with an accident

Please mention your nationality so that it's easier to understand what dialect of Spanish your translation uses.

Comment: In Cuba we say `se llevó [la roja] o [la luz] y tuvo [un accidente] o [un choque] ` speaking in that context

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The local way to say it:

> Se saltó el semáforo.

I'm spanish.

The sentence will be translated:

> Se saltó el semáforo y tuvo un accidente.

Comment: Has olvidado el acento de "saltó" ;)

Comment: ¿Que parte de España? Hay muchos dialectos regionales en la península... Y no incluyo las Canárias.

Comment: Esto es Español, se lo he escuchado decir a andaluces, catalanes y madrileños. Desconozco si los canarios tienen una palabra propia para semaforo.

Answer (score 0):

He went past the red light = Se pasó la luz roja / Se pasó el semáforo / Rebasó la luz roja / Rebasó el semáforo.

Comment: My question was about translating "he went right past the red light" and not "he went past the red light". I already know the translation for the latter. But thanks anyways.